# Error when deploying from codeship to amazon aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, codeship

I have a local git repo and I am trying to do continuous integration and deployment using Codeship. https://documentation.codeship.com

I have the github hooked up to the continuous integration and it seems to work fine.

I have an AWS account and a bucket on there with my access keys and permissions.

When I run the deploy script I get this error:
[image]

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

I had this very issue when using aws-cli and relying on the following files to hold AWS credentials and config for the default profile:

- ~/.aws/credentials
- ~/.aws/config

I suspect there is an issue with this technique; as reported in github: [Unable to locate credentials](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/915)

I ended up using codeship project's Environment Variables for the following:

- AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
- AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

Now, this is **not ideal**. However my AWS-IAM user has very limited access to perform the specific task of uploading to the bucket being used for the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, depending on your need, you could also check out the Codeshop Pro platform; it allows you to have an encrypted file with environment variables that are decrypted at runtime, during your build.

On both Basic and Pro platforms, if you want/need to use credentials in a file, you can store the credentials in environment variables (like suggested by Nigel) and then echo it into the file as part of your test setup.